# Как в цикле получить значение через одну итерацию, но исключая первое и последнее значение?

Tags: javascript

Нужно получить условие внутри цикла

```js
let data = [1, 3, 5, 8, 11, 12, 16, 18, 22];

for(let i in data){
  console.log(data[i]); //? 3, 8, 12, 18
}
```

Comment: используй не foreach а просто for где можно указать шаг  а также с какого значения начинать 
 https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = [1, 3, 5, 8, 11, 12, 16, 18, 22];

for(let i = 1; i < data.length; i += 2){
    console.log(data[i]); //? 3, 8, 12, 18
}
```